# Increment variables in functions by use keyword

Tags: php, function, laravel, variables, scope

I have problem with variable in function - I define variable outside the function, increments the var in function and displays var outside function.

My code already looks like this:

```
$count = 10;
$decrease_count = function() use (&$count) {
    $count--;
};
$decrease_count();
echo $count;

$added_records = 0;
Excel::filter("chunk")->selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load("storage\XYZ.xls")->chunk(250, function($reader) use (&$added_records, $part_catalogs, $parts, $cars, $car_models, $brands, &$importHelper) {
    $added_records++;
    echo "ADDED RECORDS LOCAL: " . $added_records . "<br>";
});
echo "<h2>Added " . $added_records . " records</h2>";
```

echo ADDED RECORDS LOCAL returns 1, so the $added_records++ works

Results: echo $count returns 9, but echo "Added " . $added_records (...) returns 0...

How to increment this $added_records variable??

Comment: `$added_records++;` Is this code is getting executed ?

Comment: To add to the above comment, put `echo "incrementing added_records";` right before `$added_records++;` and see if it gets displayed.

Comment: debugging: add `var_dump($added_records, __FILE__.__LINE__);` as the last line in the function. Why? It will show that the code is being executed and what the value is. I use the above code rather than echo as it always gives something useful for the variable rather than trying to convert it to a string. Also, it tells me where it was called from so I can remove it easily later. ;-/

Comment: Is `Excel` a custom class or is it available somewhere?

Comment: Excel is here: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: Did you check if the second closure has been executed?

Comment: Yes, it has been executed